# Have Matlab type a string as if from keyboard

Tags: matlab, keyboard, automation, user-input

I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to have MATLAB type a string for you, as if the user had typed it on the keyboard. I believe it can be done using a shell script or an applescript, but I was wondering if Matlab had a native implementation.

I have tried searching around for it, but have not had any luck. It is not super necessary, but I am just super lazy and want to write a script that will automatically enter information into an application after MATLAB has calculated stuff.

If you know of another simple way of doing this, let me know as well. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**
Adding some code that I used in response to an answer below, using the Java Robot Class

```
function robotType(text)
    import java.awt.Robot; 
    import java.awt.event.*; 
    SimKey=Robot;
    for i = 1:length(text)
        if strcmp(text(i),upper(text(i))) == 0 || all(ismember(text(i),'0123456789')) == 1
            eval(['SimKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_',upper(text(i)),')'])
            eval(['SimKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_',upper(text(i)),')'])
        else
            SimKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            eval(['SimKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_',upper(text(i)),')'])
            eval(['SimKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_',upper(text(i)),')'])
            SimKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        end
    end
end
```

Warning, code may not be the best, but hey it was written in like 5 minutes.

Comment: so what is the difference between this and saving to txt file the "typed" string, and later reading it when needed?

Comment: I need to basically enter it into an online system, that does not have a file upload system. Everything needs to be manually typed in. So I am trying to automate that, because well let's be honest, typing sucks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing an applescript to do everything that I needed Matlab to do. Unfortunately this will not help the Windows people, but myself and the other people using the script are mac users, so it works for us.

I have however, edited my question above to include code that I used initially in Matlab to auto type things. Simply run command as `robotType('SomeString')` and it will type that string.

I do not believe it will hand spaces or random characters that well, or at all, but it is good enough for abc123. Sorry for no final solution on this.